# override namespaced puts only works after overriding Kernel.puts?

Tags: ruby, overriding, puts

Sorry for the vague question title, but I have no clue what causes the following:

```
module Capistrano
  class Configuration
    def puts string
      ::Kernel.puts 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

Now when Capistrano calls `puts`, I don't see "test", but I see the original output.

However, when I also add this:

```
module Kernel
  def puts string
    ::Kernel.puts 'what gives?'
  end
end
```

Now, suddenly, `puts` actually returns "test", not "what gives?", not the original content, but "test".

Is there a reasonable explanation why this is happening (besides my limited understanding of the inner-workings of Ruby Kernel)?

Things that look off to me (but somehow "seem to work"):

- I would expect the first block to return 'test', but it didn't
- I would expect the combination of the two blocks to return 'what gives?', but it returns 'test'?
- The way I override the Kernel.puts seems like a never-ending loop to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module Capistrano
  class Configuration
    def puts string
      ::Kernel.puts 'test'
    end
    def an_thing
      puts "foo"
    end
  end
end

Capistrano::Configuration.new.an_thing
```

gives the output:

```
test
```

The second version also gives the same output.  The reason is that you're defining an instance level method rather than a class level method ([this post](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) seems to do a good job explaining the differences).  A slightly different version:

```
module Kernel
  def self.puts string
    ::Kernel.puts 'what gives?'
  end
end
```

does the following.  Because it is causing infinite recursion, like you expected.

```
/tmp/foo.rb:14:in `puts': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /tmp/foo.rb:14:in `puts'
    from /tmp/foo.rb:4:in `puts'
    from /tmp/foo.rb:7:in `an_thing'
    from /tmp/foo.rb:18

shell returned 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an answer rather than a comment because of its editing capabilities. You can edit it to add more information and I may delete it later.

> Now when Capistrano calls puts, I don't see "test", but I see the
>   original output.

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing how Capistrano calls `puts` and which one. I would say it's normal if puts displays its parameter, using the original `Kernel#puts` (it is not clear what you call *original output*, I must suppose you mean the string given to puts).

> - I would expect the first block to return 'test', but it didn't

The only way I see to call the instance method `puts` defined in the class Configuration in the module Capistrano is :

```
Capistrano::Configuration.new.puts 'xxx'
```

or

```
my_inst_var = Capistrano::Configuration.new
```

and somewhere else

```
my_inst_var.puts 'xxx'
```

and of course it prints `test`. Again, without seeing the puts statement whose result surprises you, it's impossible to tell what's going on.

> - I would expect the combination of the two blocks to return 'what gives?', but it returns 'test'?

The second point is mysterious and I need to see the code calling puts, as well as the console output.